# Scrapy - request queue size increased to gigabytes

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written few large scraper with millions of urls. They take memory more than 15GB and got killed.

The issue is with the request queue. Its size increased to thousands.

I have also used `-s job_directory = dir_name` to store request queue on hard drive but as I am facing this issue in multiple scrapers it will cost me lot of space.

Is there any way to limit request queue size?
Please suggest me a solution to this problem.

Comment: You could try changing your crawling strategy to one that will not yield as many requests at once. Or try a different request order (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-bfo-dfo).